# Choosing with source file (.cpp) to display first upon building/debugging?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was hoping someone could help me.

I am a bit new to C++ and was wondering - I have this program I did with a single .cpp source file, then I decided I might like to have a different .cpp source file appear before the original source file. A type of welcome screen if you will, you click the button and then it takes you to the original .cpp program source file.

My concern is when I go to build/debug it keeps showing me the first(original) .cpp file, how do I make it show the second(new) .cpp file first?

I hope I am making sense.....I know I've confused both Bing and Goggle with this question.

Thank you.

I also am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express if that is any help...

Comment: I'd suggest rewording this question.  Neither building nor debugging your project is supposed to display a source file. ???

Answer (score 0):

The program will always start in your main function if you want to utilize the other cpp file you need to put definitions for you class/functions/variables in a header file and include it in the second.

Comment: Ohhhh okay thank you for clarifying this, it was getting confusing, thank you guys sooooo much!

Answer (score 0):

This is some kind of ASCII art to me. Since your program will always start at main(), I suggest the following solution :

**main.cpp** :

```
/*********************
 *       HELLO
 *      WELCOME
 *     BIENVENUE
 *
 * blah blah blah
 **********************
 */

// minimal amount of code
int run_my_app(int argc, char *argv[]); // implemented elsewhere
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { return run_my_app(argc, argv); }
```

and put a breakpoint on the last line.

then **my_app.cpp** :

```
int run_my_app(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ... do stuff

   return 0;
}
```

This way, when you debug your program, it will stop on your "welcome file" because of the breakpoint, and go to the actual implementation only when you click the "run" button.

This should achieve exactly what you want.